# MYSQLI Prepared statement update statement with where in array

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I managed to create a prepared statement that updates the hardcoded values within a SQL database table using mysqli prepared statement with the Where IN statement which is containing an Array..

I need to update the `stats_accid` column of table `resetstats` with the value `$arrayresetid` from table account based on the fetched names in variable `$arrayresetname` which are store in the `username` column of the table `resetstats`.

Here is my code:

```
if ($totalacc > 0) {
    $in7 = str_repeat('?,', count($arrayidc) - 1) . '?';
    $types7 = str_repeat('s', count($arrayidc));
    $sql7 = "SELECT email,name,group_name,id FROM account WHERE name IN ($in7) AND NOT group_name = 'test'";
    $stmt7 = $mysqli->prepare($sql7);
    $stmt7->bind_param($types7, ...$arrayidc);
    $stmt7->execute();
    $result7 = $stmt7->get_result();
    while ($rowid7 = $result7->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arrayresetid = $rowid7['id'];
        $arrayresetname = $rowid7['name'];
        $arrayresetnamereplace = str_replace(" (resetted)", "", $arrayresetname);
        $arraynamereset[] = $arrayresetnamereplace;
    }

    if ($stmt7 == true) {
        $in9 = str_repeat('?,', count($arraynamereset) - 1) . '?';
        $sql9 = "UPDATE resetstats SET statsfriendly = 1,stats_accid = ? WHERE username IN ($in9) ";
        $stmt9 = $mysqli->prepare($sql9);
        $arraynamereset[] = $arrayresetid;
        $stmt9->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($arraynamereset)), ...$arraynamereset);
        $stmt9->execute();
        $stmt9->close();
    }
}
```

Example data table account:

```
id | name
865 | test name a
876 | test name b
888 | test name c
```

example data table resetstats (before update !):

```
statsid | username | statsfriendly | stats_accid
2 | test name a | 0 | 0
3 | test name b | 0 | 0
4 | test name c | 0 | 0
```

example data table resetstats (Exptected output AFTER update !):

```
statsid | username | statsfriendly | stats_accid
2 | test name a | 1 | 865 
3 | test name b | 1 | 876 
4 | test name c | 1 | 888
```

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is. Maybe if you showed what you're trying to do on a small sample of data?

Comment: I need to use a variable in this prepared statement.  UPDATE resetstats SET statsfriendly = 1,stats_accid = ? WHERE username IN ($in9) . The variable I use now is not updating the ID from table account in table resetstats  . I have no idea how to make an example out of that ?

Comment: If you turn on mysqli error handling you'll probably  find your last bind_param is failing because the number of parameters you're giving it doesn't match the number of `?`s in the query. You forgot about the `stats_accid = ?` parameter, I think. Or perhaps you haven't forgotten it, but you've put it at the end of `$arraynamereset` instead of the start where it needs to be. I'm guessing the `$arraynamereset[] = $arrayresetid;` was supposed to add that parameter? So maybe actually the error will be a type mismatch error in the SQL. Also it'll only ever use the last value of `$arrayresetid`!

Comment: Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before you open your mysqli connection, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP. Then you can get a clearer picture of what's going on.
But anyway I'm pretty sure you could do this whole thing in a single SQL UPDATE...SELECT statement without needing to pull the data out into PHP

Comment: I have that added. No errors showing so parameters are correct. The ID value is simple not updating probebly because it is an array or something but i am stuck in my mind on how to get it done..

Comment: I needs to be seperate because the match of two names in both tables. Therefor the str replace function. But i am open for ideas. As i said. I am new and this worked and does what i needs to do. But when i add the id variable that is wrong

Comment: As I said it'll only ever use the last value of $arrayresetid from your loop. So probably all your rows (assuming the WHERE clause matches any) will be set to the same ID. I assume you want it to set a different value for each user? It's actually not very clear what the outcome should be. That's why el_vanja asked for an example of some data. Show examples of the data from the first table and the second table at the start of the process, and the result you want to achieve in the second table after your code has run, based on that initial data.

Comment: I tried to give an example. See the edited question. Is this what you mean ?

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Thank you for the advice. but the whole site is writen in this so I need it in mysqli done..

Comment: What is `if ($stmt7 == true) {` supposed to do?

Comment: The idea is to only execute the statement if the previous statement is true

Comment: Why are you doing this with two queries? You can do it with an `UPDATE` query that joins with the `account` table.

Comment: That's not what it does. Also, if you enable mysqli error reporting you don't need anything like that.

Comment: Your statement number 9 should have the value prepended, so use `array_unshift` instead of pushing the value at the end

Comment: `$arrayresetid` is just the ID from the last row returned by the `SELECT` query. Your `UPDATE` will set everyone's `stats_id` set to this same ID.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. It doesn't match the output you expect. As Barmar said all rows will have the same `stats_accid` so you can't expect different one

Comment: The id is a saved value that i select from the account table. I need that value to be updated in the stats_accid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this with a single query.

```
UPDATE resetstats AS r
JOIN account AS a ON r.username = REPLACE(a.name, ' (resetted)', '')
SET r.statsfriendly = 1, r.stats_id = a.id
WHERE a.name IN ($in7)
```

Comment: Thank you! Never knew sql could be done like this!